# Can I upload one APK with a new certificate which contains a new SHA1 key to play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded one apk with a keystore certificate before. But after adding Google map to my map, I have to change the keystore and make it as releaseKeystore with a new SHA1 key. My be I did some mistake here.

So can Google Play Store will accept it and update my before apk? Or I have to publish it as a new appliocation.

Comment: Play Store doesn't allow you to upload apk files with debug keystore, are you sure it wasn't auto-signed with your default keystore ?

Comment: sorry...this was not debug..i am updating my question now..

Comment: but for google map I changed my sha1 key and create a new certificate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd change your keystore with `Google Maps`, I've never added it to any of my apps but I doubt it would force you to change your signing certificate.

After uploading an app signed with a specific keystore, you can only update it with that keystore. This is security measures to ensure the app belongs to you.

If for any reason you've lost your keystore the only thing you can do it re-upload your app with the new one (and possibly a new package name).

Save your keystores somewhere safe!